# Finding unmatched records with SQL

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying write a query to find records which don't have a matching record in another table.

For example, I have a two tables whose structures looks something like this:

```
Table1
    State | Product | Distributor | other fields
    CA    | P1      |  A          | xxxx
    OR    | P1      |  A          | xxxx
    OR    | P1      |  B          | xxxx
    OR    | P1      |  X          | xxxx
    WA    | P1      |  X          | xxxx
    VA    | P2      |  A          | xxxx

Table2
    State | Product | Version | other fields
    CA    | P1      |  1.0    | xxxx
    OR    | P1      |  1.5    | xxxx
    WA    | P1      |  1.0    | xxxx
    VA    | P2      |  1.2    | xxxx
```

(State/Product/Distributor together form the key for Table1. State/Product is the key for Table2)

I want to find all the State/Product/Version combinations which are Not using distributor X.  (So the result in this example is CA-P1-1.0, and VA-P2-1.2.)

Any suggestions on a query to do this?

Comment: from your second to last sentence, should table2 even be involved in this query? (except perhaps to get the version of the product).

Comment: I think you answered your own question.  Table2 is necessary to get the version.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table2 T2
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM
           Table1 T1
        WHERE
           T1.State = T2.State AND
           T1.Product = T2.Product AND
           T1.Distributor = 'X')
```

This should be ANSI compliant.

Comment: This works on most SQL systems; EXCEPT won't work everywhere (though it is more elegant where it does work).

Comment: Using "SELECT 1 FROM" in the sub-query (instead of "SELECT * FROM") may prevent an unnecessary table scan. Though I would expect the DBMS to  be smart enough to figure it out on it's own, upon seeing "EXISTS".

Comment: I have this with my SQL Server MVP colleague all the time :-) The * is expanded at compile time, bt collapses trivially, but not runtime he says. He showed me an article once. I saw Itzak Ben-Gan a while ago and he said the * is quicker. The choice is yours...

Comment: When using EXISTS there should be no difference between SELECT * and SELECT 1.

Comment: @Dems That's not exactly true. In Oracle, `SELECT *` in an EXISTS clause was specially optimized. Later, after internet hordes started recommending `SELECT 1` they had to go back and change their code to accommodate it. Also, according to at least one blog a year or so ago, `SELECT 1` is more efficient in Sql Server during execution plan building. It's a toss-up... making global recommendations is apparently fraught with danger.

Comment: @Emtucifor: do you have a reference for that SELECT 1 thing in SQL SErver please? I've heard this before but never seen any remotely authoritative

Comment: See [Microsoft employee Conor Cunningham's old blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/CONOR/2008/02/default.aspx?page=2) (sorry, the post itself has a URL issue so scan the page), also see that [Lutz Mueller in the comments on this blog post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/26/sql-server-select-1-vs-select-an-interesting-observation/#comment-44337) had a performance difference with IF EXISTS (). However, I'm not _claiming_ this is how Sql Server actually operates, just that I _read_ such a claim.

Comment: @gbn Just found [another blog post about it with interesting information](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2009/09/age-old-select-vs-select-1-debate.html).

Comment: @Emtucifor: Excellent. Thank you. This backs up what I've posted before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932386/how-to-avoid-null-when-using-value-name-mapping-in-sql/1932406#1932406

Answer (score 15):

In T-SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table2.State, Table2.Product, Table2.Version
FROM Table2 
  LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table1.State = Table2.State AND Table1.Product = Table2.Product AND Table1.Distributor = 'X'
WHERE Table1.Distributor IS NULL
```

No subqueries required.

Edit:  As the comments indicate, the DISTINCT is not necessary.  Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't use distinct, but otherwise this is what you want.

Comment: The distinct will probably make the query less efficient, but never more efficient. It depends on the relative table row counts. The distcnt also forces an aggregate that sub query does not need.

Comment: The performance and behavior of this query also depends heavily on whether `Distributor` is covered by the index used in the join (if not then a lookup may be required or an index operation may have to convert to a clustered index operation) and whether `Distributor` is NULLable (in which case it may return matched rows that are missing a value, in addition to unmatched rows).

Comment: What if distributor is nullable?

Answer (score 1):

select * from table1 where state not in (select state from table1 where distributor = 'X')

Probably not the most clever but that should work.

Comment: IN is not as good as EXISTS, and does not handle the composite key on state/product

Comment: Also depending on RDBMS `NOT IN` does not behave like you'd expect if `state` is nullable.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.State, t2.Product, t2.Version
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.State = t2.State AND t1.Product = t2.Product
                AND t1.Distributor <> 'X'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle:

```
SELECT t2.State, t2.Product, t2.Version
FROM Table2 t2, Table t1
WHERE t1.State(+) = t2.State
  AND t1.Product(+) = t2.Product
  AND t1.Distributor(+) = :distributor
  AND t1.State IS NULL
```