# How to avoid NULL when using Value-Name Mapping in SQL

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

I have a table like the following which is basically used to "give a name" to a value in a table (this table contains values for a bunch of other tables as well, not just for MYTABLE; I've omitted a few irrelevant fields from NAMEVALUEMAP):

```
NAMEVALUEMAP Table
---------------------
VALUE_  | NAME_
---------------------
0       | ZERO
1       | ONE
```

I didn't want to use JOINs so I thought of using Sub-Queries.
Problem is when a value does not exist in the NAMEVALUEMAP table then NULL is shown.
Instead of NULL I want to show the actual value from MYTABLE (MYTABLE has ID field as identity column and contains a few rows):

```
-- //Fine, prints word 'ZERO' when MYTABLE.ABC is 0
SELECT 
(SELECT NAME_ FROM NAMEVALUEMAP WHERE VALUE_ = (SELECT ABC FROM MYTABLE inner_ WHERE inner_.ID = outer_.ID))
FROM 
MYTABLE outer_

-- //Not Fine, prints NULL (because "999" is not in NAMEVALUEMAP). In this case, MYTABLE.ABC is 999
-- //Want it to print 999 if the value is not in NAMEVALUEMAP
SELECT 
(SELECT NAME_ FROM NAMEVALUEMAP WHERE VALUE_ = (SELECT ABC FROM MYTABLE inner_ WHERE inner_.ID = outer_.ID))
FROM 
MYTABLE outer_

-- //Tried COALESCE, but the error is "Invalid column name 'VALUE_'"
SELECT 
COALESCE((SELECT NAME_ FROM NAMEVALUEMAP WHERE VALUE_ = (SELECT ABC FROM MYTABLE inner_ WHERE inner_.ID = outer_.ID)), ABC)
FROM 
MYTABLE outer_
```

**Also**, is there **a better way** to do this sort of value-to-name mapping?

Comment: Why don't you want to use joins?

Comment: Seems like I'm wrong about JOINs being slower than sub-queries, at least in this case? Please see my reply to comments below as to what my reasoning is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend using a ***LEFT JOIN*** (is there any reason you are voidung it?) and ***ISNULL***

```
SELECT  ISNULL(NAME_, ABC)
FROM    MYTABLE m LEFT JOIN
    NAMEVALUEMAP n ON m.ABC = n.VALUE_
```

Well, in that case you can try

```
SELECT  ISNULL((select NAME_ FROM NAMEVALUEMAP WHERE VALUE_ = m.ABC), m.ABC)
FROM    MYTABLE m
```

Comment: There are 3 such "MYTABLEs" I will be selecting about 20 columns from, each of those columns need this mapping. That would become quite a complicated (looking) query, plus (I'm not sure) I suppose sub-queries will be faster than JOINs?

Comment: No, joins will be faster than sub-queries.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32705705/join-vs-subquery.aspx *In general there is no reason to assume that a subquery will be faster
or slower than a join.  Specific cases can point one way or the other,
but there are too many variables for a general answer.*

Comment: Perfect, Guruji. I shall be using the JOIN as it seems to have a better execution plan. Will come to know more in usage. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a left join, unless you want soem EXISTS/UNION construct. Not tested:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(N.VALUE, M.ABC)
FROM
    MYTABLE M
    LEFT JOIN
    NAMEVALUEMAP N ON M.VALUE N.ABC
```

If you *really* want to avoid JOINs...

```
SELECT
    ABC
FROM
    MYTABLE M
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NAMEVALUEMAP N WHERE M.VALUE N.ABC)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    VALUE
FROM
    NAMEVALUEMAP N
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE M WHERE M.VALUE N.ABC)
```

Edit:

The SELECT *, 1 or NULL in EXISTS question again

- Try `EXISTS (SELECT 1/0...)`
- Mentioned in [ANSI SQL 1992 Standard too, page 191](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

Comment: I'm able to do this with JOINs but I want to avoid doing JOINs if I can. Please also see me reply to comment by astander on my reasoning for not using JOINs. I hope i'm right about that?

Comment: select * can be a bit expensive for an exists in some DBMS, I would normally use select 1 instead

Comment: Database engines are designed to JOIN. A subquery will most likely generate more IO and a worse plan because it's a subquery for each column. One join = gets all columns.

Comment: @Steve De Caux: it's not evaluated. Try `EXISTS (SELECT 1/0...)`. It hasn't been evaluated on SQL Server since at least SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @Steve De Caux: Mentioned in ANSI SQL 1992 Standard too, page 191 http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: Fair comment, old habits die hard (I mean old)

Comment: Well I think I will be using JOINs.. :) But one thing to note is that in my case, ISNULL() is the option that will work, and not COALESCE(). Thats because NAMEVALUEMAP.NAME_ is varchar and the value from the MYTABLE is an INT. Thusly I get conversion error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'One' to data type tinyint." Thank you

Comment: ISNULL is SQL Server specific and takes the 1st datatype. COALESCE is ANSI standard and works a bit differently. I'd use ISNULL

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(
   (SELECT NAME_ FROM NAMEVALUEMAP WHERE VALUE_ = 
      (SELECT ABC FROM MYINNERTABLE inner_ WHERE inner_.ID = outer_.ID)
   ),
   <int to string>(
      SELECT ABC FROM MYINNERTABLE inner_ WHERE inner_.ID = outer_.ID
   )
)

FROM 
MYTABLE outer_
```

where column function `<int to string>` is appropriate for sqlserver. In mysql it would be CAST(). Without conversion, the query will throw a wobbly about the mismatched datatypes.

Comment: I don't think that would work for me - the value to be mapped to a name comes from a different table..

Comment: In your question you used the same table name (MYTABLE) for inner_ and outer_ => I assumed it was the same table. I've edited to accomodate your comment