# Find unmatched records from 2 tables using Access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to find unmatched records in both tables(contains more than 100 records in both) using below query (query was built from access query wizard)

Table A

```
    EC ID   wt
     1001   339.55
     1007   3.77
     1008   1.76
     1009   13.48
     1010   5.86
     1011   11.58
     1012   37.89
     1013      4.88
     1015      6.98
```

Table B

```
     EC ID  wt_xxxx
     1001   339.55
     1002      1.99
     1003      1.78
     1004       2
     1007   3.77
     1008   1.76
     1009   13.48
     1010   5.86
     1011   11.58
     1012   37.89
```

Query1 retruns all records in table A those are not in table B.

```
  SELECT A.[EC ID], A.wt 
  FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.[EC ID] = B.[EC ID]
   WHERE (((B.[EC ID]) Is Null));
```

Returns

```
   EC ID    wt
   1013      4.88
   1015      6.98
```

Similarly Query2 retruns all records in table B those are not in table A.

```
  SELECT B.[EC ID], B.wt_xxxx
  FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON B.[EC ID] =A.[EC ID]
  WHERE (((A.[EC ID]) Is Null));
```

Returns

```
    EC ID    wt_xxxx
     1002      1.99
     1003      1.78
     1004       2
```

when running second query the access is closing itself . But in sometimes it gives result . Couldn't understand why. is there any efficient way to do it. i used a query in stackoverflow 
         [Finding unmatched records with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508509/finding-unmatched-records-with-sql.but) performance is very poor it takes 15min to get result. Any other solution is there with unmatched records query?

Comment: by more than 100 records, do you mean few hundreds? And the query from the linked post takes 15 minutes? can you post the access file somewhere, I'm curious :)

Answer (score 0):

if a record will only appear once in a table

```
select count(*),EC ID,wt_xxxx
from (select B.[EC ID], B.wt_xxxx
      TABLEB B
      union all
      select A.[EC ID], A.wt_xxxx
      TABLEB A) q
group by EC ID,wt_xxxx
having count(*) =1
```

OR
using what you have. You are close, just use a full outer join to look for nulls in either table

```
  SELECT B.[EC ID], B.wt_xxxx, A.[EC ID], A.wt_xxxx, 
  FROM B FULL OUTER JOIN A ON B.[EC ID] =A.[EC ID]
  WHERE A.[EC ID] Is Null or B.[EC ID] Is Null  ;
```