# A query or datatable is required to find the difference between two tables

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a table between some products and another table with some products. I want to specify only the different products between the two tables.

table prod a --col prodnama
gh1
cd2
at3

table prodb --col prodnamb
at3
cd2

Result   gh1

I want to query ms access, and it works on Visual Basic.net if there is datatable or use for it

Comment: What do you mean by `table`?  Your question is tagged `vb.net`.  There is not a `table` data type in `vb.net`

Comment: hi devlin  .   I want to query ms access, and it works on Visual Basic.net if there is datatable or use for it

Comment: You want to know which products are in proda and not in prodb? Build a Find Unmatched query. Access has a query wizard for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding unmatched records with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508509/finding-unmatched-records-with-sql) also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003586/find-unmatched-records-from-2-tables-using-access-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there are two parts to your question. **First** you want to create a "find unmatched query, and **second**, you want to query Access and then load the result into a VB.Net datatable. The following code is for VB.Net. Change the connection string for your version of OLEDB and the path to your database.

You'll need the MS Access redistributable installed (free).  It has ODBC and OleDb drivers that you will need.

You will need a connection string to your Access database:

```
Dim strOleDB As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data" & _
" Source=C:\MyPath\MyDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

And a dataset to load your table into:

```
Dim dst As New DataSet()
```

Get your SQL; something like:

```
strSQL = "Select table1.column_a from table1" & 
" Left Join table2 on table1.column_a = table2.column_a" & _
" Where table2.column_a Is Null"
```

Load your datatable:

```
Dim tblData As DataTable = LoadDataAccess(dst, strSQL, "tmpMyData", strOleDB)
```

tblData has your result list.

I typically do this with a function to return my datatable.  Something like this:

```
    Function LoadDataAccess(ByVal dstToLoadInto As DataSet, 
        ByVal strSQL As String, 
        ByVal strName As String, 
        strOleDB as String) As DataTable
    Dim cnnAccess As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strOleDB)
    Dim dptAccess = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, cnnAccess)
    Dim tblNew As DataTable
    Try
        dstToLoadInto.Tables.Remove(strName)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    cnnAccess.Open()
    Try
        dptAccess.Fill(dstToLoadInto, strName)
        tblNew = dstToLoadInto.Tables(strName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        cnnAccess.Close()
    End Try

    Return tblNew
End Function
```

This video goes through steps on how to compare lists using SQL (for strSQL above):
https://youtu.be/IkrDKdfQmuk

Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 1):

This will return all the products in proda which are not in prodb.

```
Select prodnama 
from proda 
left join prodb
on proda.prodnama = prodb.prodnamb
where prodb.prodnamb is null
```

This will return all the products in prodb which are not in proda.

```
Select prodnamb
from prodb 
left join proda
on prodb.prodnamb = proda.prodnama 
where prodb.prodnama is null
```

And if you want all the products in proda which are not in prodb and all the products in prodb which are not in proda in a single query

```
Select prodnama as prodnam
from proda 
left join prodb
on proda.prodnama = prodb.prodnamb
where prodb.prodnamb is null
Union
Select prodnamb as prodnam
from prodb 
left join proda
on prodb.prodnamb = proda.prodnama 
where prodb.prodnama is null
```