# Get Unmatched records from the 3 table

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 3 tables. The first table 'Status_Mapping' has following columns

```
Status_original  Status_Site
accepted         Call Verified
duplicate        Duplicate Leads
dq               DQ
```

'Lead_transaction' has the columns:

```
Lead_transaction_id   Rate   Status
  11                  0.01   accepted
  12                  0.02   accepted
  13                  0.01   newstatus
```

'Lead_Instance' table:

```
Lead_Instance_id   Lead_transaction_id   product_id  affiliate_id
 1                    11                   6            10
 2                    12                   7            11
 3                    13                   6            10
```

What I want to do is  get the count(lead_instance_id) and sum(rate) for status which are not present in status_mapping table and should display status as "other",  with product_id = 6 and affiliate_id = 10 My End result should be like

```
Total              Sum   Status
 1                 0.01  Other
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding unmatched records with SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508509/finding-unmatched-records-with-sql)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can start with this query:

```
select count(distinct a.Lead_Instance_id), sum(b.Rate)
from
Lead_Instance as a
inner join
Lead_transaction as b
on (a.Lead_transaction_id = b.Lead_transaction_id)
where
b.Status not in (select distinct Status_original from Status_Mapping)
and a.product_id = 6
and a.affiliate_id = 10
```