# Find unmatched record and specify the field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want your kind help to give a solution to match between two tables and return unmatched recorda with a field specify which field was unmatched.

Take a note that each table including more than 30 fields.

Comment: Are you looking for SQL query which returns the output of unmatched value in two different tables right.

Comment: Yes exactly and add new expression specify in which field there was unmatched data

Comment: There is a lot of fields inside each table ( more than 30 field) how can be handled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding unmatched records with SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508509/finding-unmatched-records-with-sql)

Comment: are you using MySQL or sqlite

Comment: I am using SQL Language

Comment: Have you tried Access's Find Unmatched query wizard from the Query Wizard menu? The wizard only works on a single field at a time, but switching to SQL view will help you build the syntax for the other fields.

Comment: Yes but it do a match for one field,  what i want to do is to match all fields on the table and know which field was changed, if there an code in vba access can be used please let me know as i need to finalize my project

Comment: Please need support

Comment: You will probably need to build a separate query for each field. If you combine them all in a single query, how will you know which field of the 30 is different? You won't. If there is a separate query comparing each field, and you run them from VBA, any results returned after the query is opened as a recordset would give you a clear indication of the field and records that are mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recordsets but if your tables are long this might take a while. This is absolutely not optimized, but considering how little information you provided, I don't want to invest a whole lot of time.

I am assuming your tables are identical in structure, sorted identically, and have the same number of records. If not, feel free to adapt this however you see fit, but you should be able to get the idea of what I am doing.

It will output the field and row number of `Table1` in the immediate window when a mismatch is found. You could also insert it into a temp table if you want to recover all of the field values, but again, I don't want to go that far. So this has limitations:

```
Public Function FindMisMatches(Table1 As String, Table2 As String)

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim Row As Integer

On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(Table1, dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(Table2, dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

rs1.MoveFirst
rs2.MoveFirst
Row = 1
Do Until rs1.EOF Or rs2.EOF
    'Assuming both tables have identical structure
    For i = 1 To rs1.Fields.Count - 1
        If rs1.Fields(i).Value <> rs2.Fields(i).Value Then
            Debug.Print "Mismatch in field " & rs1.Fields(i).Name & " on row " & Row
        End If
    Next i
rs1.MoveNext
rs2.MoveNext
Row = Row + 1
Loop

Debug.Print "End of recordset"

Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Exit Function

PROC_ERR:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & "; " & Err.Description
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set rs2 = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher D. But in which the code should be added ?

Comment: Add this to a module. In the immediate window, type: `?modulename.FindMisMatches("table1name", "table2name")` where you replace the object placeholders with the actual names of your module and tables. Then press enter.

Comment: Thank Christopher D. it is worked fine :)
Is there a way to run the code automatically and show a result on the form

Comment: Yes, but not without modifying the code I posted. Research how to manipulate recordsets and write to a table. Alternatively (and better), using 30 unmatched queries combined in a `UNION` would be the fastest and easiest approach and will not need a temporary table.