# SQL unwanted results in NOT query

Tags: mysql, left-join

This looks like it should be really easy question, but I've been looking for an answer for the past two days and can't find it. Please help!

I have two tables along the lines of

```
texts.text_id, texts.other_stuff...
pairs.pair_id, pairs.textA, pairs.textB
```

The second table defines pairs of entries from the first table.

What I need is the reverse of an ordinary LEFT JOIN query like:

```
SELECT texts.text_id
FROM texts 
    LEFT JOIN text_pairs
    ON texts.text_id = text_pairs.textA 
WHERE text_pairs.textB = 123 
ORDER BY texts.text_id
```

How do I get **exclusively** the texts that are **not** paired with A given textB? I've tried

```
WHERE text_pairs.textB != 123 OR WHERE text_pairs.textB IS NULL
```

However, this returns **all** the pairs where textB is not 123. So, in a situation like

```
textA   TextB
1         3
1         4
2         4
```

if I ask for *textB != 3*, the query returns 1 and 2. I need something that will just give me 1.

Comment: With LEFT JOIN you need to filter in the ON clause and not in the WHERE clause... if you use the WHERE clause the LEFT JOIN is converted into a INNER JOIN

Comment: For next time, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you! Re. MCVE, also thank you, and noted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding unmatched records with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508509/finding-unmatched-records-with-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: Google 'stackoverflow (sql OR database) join how do I get rows that are not paired with'. This is a faq, because people do not google many clear, concise specific ways of stating their problem/solution/question. If you don't find an answer in many hits, use one as your title. Observe that using your 'How do I get exclusively the texts that are not paired with  A...' generates spurious locking hits from 'exclusively' while 'texts' & 'A' are too specific; indeed using 'how do i get only the values that are not paired table' gives your answer 1st hit. So investigate how to google.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison on the second table goes in the *ON* clause.  Then you add a condition to see if there is no match:

```
SELECT t.text_id
FROM texts t LEFT JOIN
     text_pairs tp
     ON t.text_id = tp.textA AND tp.textB = 123 
WHERE tp.textB IS NULL
ORDER BY t.text_id ;
```

This logic is often expressed using `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`:

```
select t.*
from texts t
where not exists (select 1
                  from text_pairs tp
                  where t.text_id = tp.textA AND tp.textB = 123 
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm and makes a lot more sense than what I was trying to do

Comment: Why do you answer such obvious faqs?