# Find records from table 1 that are not in table 2

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've created a query that list employees that have completed courses. I'm now trying to list all employees that have not completed a certain course. For example, if an employee has not taken first aid, I want that listed.

I have tried using NOT EXISTS and NOT IN clauses, but they either return empty tables or errors.

Here is my current query to list all completed courses (saved as qryAllCompletedCourses):

```
SELECT tblEmployee.EmpID, tblEmployee.[LastName] & ", " & [FirstName] AS EmpName, tblCourses.CatelogID, tblEmployeeScheduled.Attended, tblCourses.CourseDateTime
FROM tblCourses INNER JOIN (tblEmployee INNER JOIN tblEmployeeScheduled ON tblEmployee.EmpID = tblEmployeeScheduled.EmpID) ON tblCourses.CourseID = tblEmployeeScheduled.CourseID
WHERE (((tblEmployeeScheduled.Attended)=True))
ORDER BY tblEmployee.[LastName] & ", " & [FirstName]

UNION

SELECT tblEmployee.EmpID, tblEmployee.[LastName] & ", " & [FirstName] AS EmpName, tblIndividualLearning.CatelogID, tblIndividualLearning.Completed, tblIndividualLearning.DateCompleted
FROM tblEmployee INNER JOIN tblIndividualLearning ON (tblEmployee.EmpID = tblIndividualLearning.EmpID) AND (tblEmployee.EmpID = tblIndividualLearning.EmpID)
WHERE (((tblIndividualLearning.Completed)=True));
```

From there, I want the user to be able to select a course like first aid (CatelogID = 8) and list all employees from tblEmployee that have not taken it.

This is all I have, but all it's doing is returning people that have completed CatelogID 8.

```
SELECT tblEmployee.EmpID, qryAllCompletedCourses.CatelogID
FROM tblEmployee LEFT JOIN qryAllCompletedCourses ON tblEmployee.EmpID = qryAllCompletedCourses.EmpID
WHERE (((qryAllCompletedCourses.CatelogID)=8));
```

Comment: What Database system?

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the table schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it different ways. The `LEFT JOIN` way that you have selected needs to be written like this:

```
SELECT tblEmployee.EmpID, a.CatelogID
FROM tblEmployee LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM qryAllCompletedCourses WHERE qryAllCompletedCourses.CatelogID=8) a
ON tblEmployee.EmpID = a.EmpID
WHERE a.EmpID IS NULL;
```

Please note that the above query is "Access specific", as Access does not allow any conditions in the ON clause that are not the direct comparison between the columns of the joined tables. With any other RDBMS you would use this query:

```
SELECT tblEmployee.EmpID, qryAllCompletedCourses.CatelogID
FROM tblEmployee LEFT JOIN 
qryAllCompletedCourses 
ON tblEmployee.EmpID = qryAllCompletedCourses.EmpID and qryAllCompletedCourses.CatelogID=8
WHERE a.EmpID IS NULL;
```

The other way of doing it is to use the NOT IN:

```
SELECT tblEmployee.EmpID
FROM tblEmployee 
WHERE tblEmployee.EmpID NOT IN (SELECT EmpID FROM qryAllCompletedCourses 
     WHERE qryAllCompletedCourses.CatelogID=8);
```

And to complete it all here is a way of doing it with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT tblEmployee.EmpID
FROM tblEmployee 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM qryAllCompletedCourses 
    WHERE qryAllCompletedCourses.CatelogID=8 and 
    tblEmployee.EmpID = qryAllCompletedCourses.EmpID);
```

Comment: I went with your top solution. It works perfectly, but I'm not really sure why! Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  NOT IN

```
SELECT tblEmployee.EmpID
FROM tblEmployee 
WHERE tblEmployee.EmpID NOT IN (SELECT EmpID FROM qryAllCompletedCourses 
     WHERE qryAllCompletedCourses.CatelogID=8);
```

Comment: I gave that a try, but it seems you can't query more than one item when using NOT IN. I may have misunderstood the error, but it didn't work when I had more than one field in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You say you've tried `NOT IN`... Did your query look like this?

```
SELECT tblEmployee.EmpID, qryAllCompletedCourses.CatelogID
FROM tblEmployee LEFT JOIN qryAllCompletedCourses ON tblEmployee.EmpID = 
qryAllCompletedCourses.EmpID
WHERE tblEmployee.EmpID NOT IN (
                  SELECT tblEmployee.EmpID
                  FROM tblEmployee 
                  LEFT JOIN qryAllCompletedCourses ON tblEmployee.EmpID = qryAllCompletedCourses.EmpID
                  WHERE (((qryAllCompletedCourses.CatelogID)=8))
                                );
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use an **"*Unmatched* query"**.

For example, to list records in `Table1` that don't have matching `ID`'s in `Table2`, you would use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE Table2.ID Is Null;
```

---

Since you're using Access, the easiest way is to use the **Query Wizard** to build the query autoatically.

> 1. One the **Create** tab, in the **Queries** group, click **Query Wizard**.
>    [image: The Queries group in the Access ribbon displays two options: Query Wizard and Query Design]
> 2. In the **New Query** dialog box, double-click **Find Unmatched Query Wizard**.
> 3. Select the table that has unmatched records, then click **Next**.
>    [image: Select a table or query in the Find Unmatched Query Wizard dialog box]
> 4. Select the table that is related, and then click **Next**.
>    [image: img]
> 5. Select the fields that relate the tables, click [image: < = >], and then click **Next**. You can choose only one field from each table.  Verify that the correct fields are matched by reviewing the text in the **Matching fields** box.
>    [image: Select the matching fields from the tables in the Find Unmatched Query Wizard dialog box]
>    Note that the certain fields may already be selected if there are *existing [relationships](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guide-to-table-relationships-55b8db2c-9480-4269-b1bb-f6ec09623dfd)*.
> 6. Double-click the fields that you want to see from the first table, and then click **Next**.
>    [image: Select the fields you want to see in the query output in the Find Unmatched Query Wizard dialog box]
> 7. You can choose to view the results or to modify the design of your query.  Enter a name for the query, and then click **Finish**.
>    [image: Enter a name for your unmatched query in the Find Unmatched Query Wizard dialog box]
>
> You may want to modify your query's design to add other criteria, to change the sort order, or to add or to remove fields.
>
> <sup>(Adapted from the [**Source**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/compare-two-tables-and-find-records-without-matches-cb20ad48-4eba-402a-b20d-eaf10a5d1cb4))</sup>

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**Compare two tables and find records without matches**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/compare-two-tables-and-find-records-without-matches-cb20ad48-4eba-402a-b20d-eaf10a5d1cb4)
- Stack Overflow : [**Finding unmatched records with SQL**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/508509/8112776)
- Database Journal : [**Three Ways to Identify Non-matching Records in MySQL**](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/three-ways-to-identify-non-matching-records-in-mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the same using `SQL` left join:

```
Select * 
FROM T1 
left join  T2 ON T1 .id = T2.id
WHERE T2.id is null
```